# Underscore breaking HTML syntax highlighting in PyCharm

Tags: html, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, pycharm

I'm doing internationalization for my app and I'm using `_` to translate the text. Though it breaks PyCharm's syntax highlighting in the HTML template.

How can I get syntax highlighting back?

Thanks

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: I added the image. It's with Jinja2.